# Table of Contents for Math Equations in Latex

Tags: latex

What's the best way to have equations in LaTeX reference back to a table of contents at the beginning of a document? Something similar to the way that chapters and subchapters easily make a table of contents at the beginning of a document.  Is there a clear method for doing this?

Comment: Hi, you might get better answers over at https://tex.stackexchange.com/ (A sibling of StackOverflow focused on Tex/LaTex/etc)

Comment: Have a look at the  `tocloft` package, this allows you to create a list of equations

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.